# On Ubuntu 20.04, how to mount a LUKS2 partition?

Tags: encryption, luks

After formatting an empty ext4 partition with

```
cryptsetup --type luks2 luksFormat /dev/sda1
```

I can open it with

```
cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/sda1 MyLabel
```

It is visible as `/dev/mapper/MyLabel`.

However, when I then try to mount it with

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/MyLabel /mnt/MyLabel
```

I get this error message:

```
mount: /mnt/MyLabel: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/MyLabel, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Isn't it already mounted to `/dev/mapper/MyLabel`?

Comment: You need to create the filesystem _after_ mapping the encrypted device. By formatting the LUKS device you effectively destroyed the ext4 filesystem that was on the partition before.

Comment: @Sebastian You're right.  Had missed that. After mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/MyLabel I could mount it. Many thanks.